# pylab bargraph query

Tags: matplotlib

i am relatively new to plotting in pylab and here is a question. I have a text file containing words that have lengths ranging from 2 to 10 and now my task is to plot the frequencies of each of the word categories using bargraph. I was able to write the script and plot it but the xtick labels are screwed up and i am wondering what is the reason for this. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
two_letter=[]
three_letter=[]
four_letter=[]
five_letter=[]
six_letter=[]
seven_letter=[]
eight_letter=[]
nine_letter=[]
ten_letter=[]

inFile = open('words.txt')
for line in inFile.readlines():
    fields = line.split(' ')
    for word in fields:
        if len(word) == 2:
            two_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 3:
            three_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 4:
            four_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 5:
            five_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 6:
            six_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 7:
            seven_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 8:
            eight_letter.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 9:
            nine_letter.append(word)
        else: 
            len(word) == 10
            ten_letter.append(word)
two_l = len(two_letter)
three_l = len(three_letter)
four_l = len(four_letter)
five_l = len(five_letter)
six_l = len(six_letter)
seven_l = len(seven_letter)
eight_l = len(eight_letter)
nine_l = len(nine_letter)
ten_l = len(ten_letter)

all = [two_l,three_l,four_l,five_l,six_l,seven_l,eight_l,nine_l,ten_l]
cord = range(1,10)
labels = ["two_let", "three_let", "four_let", "five_let", "six_let", "seven_let", "eight_let", "nine_let", "ten_let"]


import pylab
pylab.bar(cord,all, color='#88aa33')
xticks(cord, labels, rotation='vertical')
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword argument `align` in the bar command to have the labels in the center of the bars:

```
pylab.bar(cord,all, color='#88aa33', align='center')
```

To make more space for the labels, you can adjust the size and position of the plot with the `subplots_adjust` function:

```
subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
```

Making enough space for the labels can also been done automatically with:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_area_auto_adjustable
make_axes_area_auto_adjustable(gca())
```